# Is it possible for a Druid to defeat a Wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons

We're currently all level 4, about to become lvl 5 and have just finished our first real campaign (LmoP). It was a lot of fun, and we're all quite comfortable with our classes by now. Our DM has talked a couple times about how it might be fun to do a battle royale one-shot when we reach lvl 5, so he has time to prepare the next campaign. This wouldn't actually count for the story, and nobody will lose their character, so we're all pretty interested to see how we'd fare against each other. This is 5e, by the way.

I'm playing a lvl 4 Circle of the Moon Druid. Most of the group I'm pretty sure I can stand up to in battle, but I'm stuck on the Wizard. More specifically on his Counterspell. I just can't figure out how to get around that.

Which made me wonder - just how hard would it be to win against a Wizard? Do any of you maybe have any tips on how to deal with the guy? Or should I run for the hills and come back when he's down?

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: Hi Iniko, welcome to the rpg.se! Please take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what this stack is about and earn your first badge! The reason you are getting downvotes is that this is not a discussion board, you should ask this question in a forum. Maybe [this question and its answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51258/how-is-counterspell-a-fair-spell) can help you.

Comment: This question is not answerable in the format of the Stack (one or more authoritative answers) and is more suitable to a forum or social media post (undirected discussion).

Comment: How would a Wizard have any chance against a _Moon_ Druid on level 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, anything is possible. You may need to use some strategies to bolster your chances but it is possible. Attempting to get right next to a wizard and cast spells when they have counterspell will probably not work out well. Some sample strategies include:

- Exploiting Circle of Moon wildshape abilities to turn into tank-like beasts or beasts with good damage output. Such as Brown Bear, Dire Wolf, or Giant Spider.
- Using the limitations of Counterspell against the wizard by casting spells with longer than 60ft range or after the wizard has used their reaction.
- Convincing other players to team up to attack the wizard to eliminate a stronger threat.
- Concealing yourself behind total cover to prevent spells from being directed at you.
- Make sure the DM has rules for determining what you're casting from the wizard's side. There are optional rules in the new Xanthar's book that I quite like. But the wizard shouldn't just know what you're casting. It should follow steps like 1) Declare cast a spell action. You and the DM know what the spell is and the slot level used. 2) Wizard can choose to use their reaction to attempt to Counterspell your spell. 3) Resolve effects.
- Attempt to trick the wizard and get them to Counterspell a low level spell. Since at 5th level a full caster only has two third level spell slots, the wizard needs to weight using them between Counterspell, other third level spells, and upcasting lower level spells.

Comment: Oh, that would work, yeah! Thank you very much for the advice. I didn't even know that Counterspell had a 60ft limit! =)

Comment: Just make sure you talk with your DM if your character would know about the limitations of counterspell. Otherwise it is metagaming which can ruin the fun.